# $X$ contractible implies reduced homology groups are trivial.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a contractible space, i.e. the identity map $1_X$ is homotopic to a constant map.

I know the following two theorems in Hatcher:

(1) If $f,g: X \to Y$ are homotopic maps, then $f_* = g_*: H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$

(2) If $f: X \to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence (i.e. there is $g: Y \to X$ with $f \circ g \sim 1_Y, g \circ f \sim 1_X$) then $f_*$ is an isomorphism.

Hatcher then claims that if $X$ is contractible, then $\tilde{H}_n(X)= 0$ for all $n \geq 0$. How does this follow from these theorems?

Is it maybe the case that if $X$ is contractible to a point $x \in X$, then the inclusion $\{x\} \to X$ is a homotopy equivalence?

Comment: Since $\tilde{H}_n(pt) = 0$ for all $n$, (2) implies the same is true for $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your last guess is exactly right. A contraction is a map $F: X \times [0, 1] \to X$ which is the identity at time $0$ and constant (say landing on the point $x$) at time $1$.

To see that this gives a homotopy equivalence between $X$ and a one point space, we need to check two things:

If we take the inclusion $\iota$ of $\{ x \}$ into $X$, and the constant map $X$ \to $\{ x \}$, then the compositions
$$
\{ x \} \to X \to \{x\}
$$
and
$$
X \to \{ x \} \to X
$$
must both be homotopic to the identity. The first of these is always true (indeed that map is, vacuously, equal to the identity). The second is true because $F$ is the desired homotopy.